# resx files for DNX 4.5.1 ConsoleApp

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, resx, dnx

resx files are not working with DNX 4.5.1 ConsoleApp [image: See here]

I added a folder "Resources" and two resx files "Resource.resx" and "Resource.de-DE.resx". 
"Resource.resx" contains a string with the name "T" and the value "US". 
"Resource.de-DE.resx" contains a string with the name "T" and the value "DE".

now I'm using this code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Resources.Resource.T);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
    Console.WriteLine(Resources.Resource.T);
}
```

The output is: 
US
US

The same code works perfectly in a .Net 4.5.1 application.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug, if you run the application with "dnx run" it works, if you run it in VS it won't. See: https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/151